# Can temporal tables be applied to a view?

Tags: sql-server

Title says it all - I can apply system versioning to a table, but can it be done to a view?

Comment: Views are just a virtual table defined by a `SELECT`. Views don't have a history as they don't store any data; all the data is in the table and so too, therefore, is the historical data. It doesn't make any sense for a view to be temporal.

Answer (score 5):

**You can't** apply temporal table system versioning to a view directly.

**[You can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#using-views-with-as-of-sub-clause-in-temporal-queries)** ensure all/some of the tables referenced by the view have it configured and then use `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` when selecting from the view however.

> SQL Server will apply AS OF clause transparently to all temporal
> tables that participate in view definition. Furthermore, you can
> combine temporal with non-temporal tables in the same view and AS OF
> will be applied only to temporal ones.